# What is the name of this mechanism for raising and lowering the impression cylinder of a printing press?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining

It is like a cam that has an off-center hole, and it rotates in its fixture with a knob to lock it in place. The purpose is that you can loosen the knob and rotate the piece to slightly raise and lower the shaft that is connected on the other end.

Does this have a name? Is it a commonly-available part or is it something that has to be custom machined?

This is for a printing press, used to adjust the vertical position of the impression cylinder a couple thousandths of an inch.

[image: Mechanism]

Comment: it's hard to tell from the picture, but I'd call it an 'eccentric cam' or simply 'eccentric'.  You might need to machine something custom to fit your particular application, but these parts are pretty simple and can often be made with ordinary manual machining techniques.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a *trunnion adjustment*.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? It's not that I don't trust you, it just might help.

Comment: @hazzey No, I just happen to know what it is.

Comment: That describes what it's doing, not the mechanism for doing it.